# APT installed a lot of packages that won't go with autoremove after removing

Tags: vim, apt

I installed the package `vim-gnome` just to try it. It installed all these additional packages when `apt-get` was called:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome 

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  fonts-lato javascript-common libjs-jquery libruby2.3 rake ruby
  ruby-did-you-mean ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert
  ruby-test-unit ruby2.3 rubygems-integration vim-gui-common zip
Paquetes sugeridos:
  apache2 | lighttpd | httpd ri ruby-dev bundler cscope vim-doc
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  fonts-lato javascript-common libjs-jquery libruby2.3 rake ruby
  ruby-did-you-mean ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert
  ruby-test-unit ruby2.3 rubygems-integration vim-gnome vim-gui-common zip
0 actualizados, 16 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
```

Then I used `sudo apt-get remove vim-gnome` to uninstall it and `sudo apt-get autoremove` to delete its dependencies, but only `vim-gui-common` is removed.

Which command do I need to remove all these packages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question isn't really about programming, and would be a much better fit for unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com